# Jquery click handler is stuck in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an handler on clicking an element. It is getting stuck in an infinite loop. How can I turn off the listener for the 2nd click in this code... so that it doesn't keep repeating.

I'm trying to automatically close the toggle after 4.5 seconds. But the close click triggers another click... and so on...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
             setTimeout(function () {
                $(".navbar-toggle").click();
             }, 4500);
          });
      });
```

Comment: use `$(".navbar-toggle").on('click',function(){});` instead of `$(".navbar-toggle").click();`

Comment: @AdarshMohan that is not working

Comment: You should not be doing `$(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
                $(".navbar-toggle").click();
          });` Period ! There should be some callback function that should be invoked rather. You are triggering an event here manually feels like hack.

You should post what is the problem you are trying to solve exactly.

Comment: I do not understand, $(".navbar-toggle") will toggle the visibility / popup of the navbar? and you want to close it after 4.5s since it is opened?

Comment: @AdarshMohan There is no difference between them .

Comment: I understand everyones concerns. I have things I can't touch. Like it or not I am just trying to modify the above code to not get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @yaochiqkl :  There are differences, on is an event listener and the other is to trigger an event.

Comment: @AdarshMohan https://api.jquery.com/click/ Nope. If there is handler function inside the parameter , it's a bind event instead of trigger . Check it  if you don't know it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 'flag' variable to your code

```
var has_clicked = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
        if(!has_clicked){
            setTimeout(function () {
                has_clicked = true;
                $(".navbar-toggle").click();
            }, 4500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: has_clicked = true should before click()? Or it will run into callback loop without setting the flag to false?

Comment: You're right about the order, sorry about that!, I'll edit my answer

Comment: I believe this edited version will still only work one time

Comment: When the user clicks, it will wait 4.5 seconds, switch the flag to true, and reclick the element after which it will fail the condition and just do nothing. If you want to run this multiple time you could just reset the flag to false after the nav has closed.

Comment: working with this answer now... trying it with a slight modifcation

Comment: I added a piece to your code. It was basically what I needed though

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  function callback2(){
      $("#test").one("click", callback1);
  }

  function callback1(){
      console.log('hi');
      setTimeout(callback2, 4500);
  }

  $("#test").one("click", callback1);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/szevtk0q/)

Is this similar to what you want?

---

Attach the click event which execute only once, using `.one()`,
do whatever you want in the callback function, and attach it again after 4.5 seconds. If you cannot even modify your code to this, please let me know, I will try to think another work around

Comment: I like this. I'm trying another solution real quick but I see your snippit works well

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am going with for now though I believe I will use shole's approach when I get some more time... for now this is working well.

```
var is_open = false;
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
          if(!is_open){
            setTimeout(function () {
                is_open = true;
                $(".navbar-toggle").click();
                is_open = false;
            }, 3500);
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: This does have an issue where if you click the toggle before 3.5 seconds it opens it an extra time... but the final state is always right and I don't anticipate it being pressed a second time in 3.5 seconds. @shole has the better solution that I will implement at some point. For now this 'works'

Comment: Just right before you commented, I want to point out that it has a problem when you click multiple times real fast...but anyway glad that you solve your problem :)

Comment: Your solution is the best. I will get around to it at some point to do it right. You can see it at DelawareTennisAcademy.com